# post put on hold, no feedback, edited it several times, made comments but no reply from mods for days, now closed im blocked from new questions

Tags: support, moderation, moderators

I think Ive corrected the problems and waited long enough, but with no feedback or replies from the initial mod its pretty frustrating and feels like he was just taking his angst out on me. This is not a good way to encourage engagement with the site...

[How to install multiple PHP versions in Debian 9, Virtualmin 6, Apache FCGI & avoid Error 500?](https://serverfault.com/questions/950146/how-to-install-multiple-php-versions-in-debian-9-virtualmin-6-apache-fcgi-av)

please can i get this looked at , or i will just have to re-post it...
regards,
Hayden.

Answer (score 6):

Closing a question (same thing as putting it on hold) has nothing to do with being encouraging or not.  It's a way to pause activity on a question while issues with it are being resolved.

Your question did/does have issues (more on that in a bit), so accusing someone of "taking their angst out on you" is counterproductive - that's deinitely not what happened.  Re-posting the question would also be counterproductive, the new question would just get closed immediately.

By contrast, asking for more information here on meta *is* productive:

Your question initially had an answer as part of the question.  It's fine to post both a question and your own answer if you want to share information, but you have to do them separately.

When you moved the answer to your original "stub" answer, you did the right thing flagging your updated answer.  I undeleted the answer, but as I said in response to your flag, I thought the question could still be clearer - what were you trying to do and why? - so I didn't re-open it.

Your question did have a re-open vote, which put it in the queue to be looked at by experienced users to decide if it should be re-opened.  3 users voted to leave it closed, however, so it stayed closed.

Since it's a pretty specific question and you've posted your own solution, I'm not sure how likely it is that you'd get any other answers even if the question was re-opened.  You could try editing the question to make it clearer why you're doing this, exactly how the error was showing up, etc. and see if it gets a re-opened the next time it goes through the review queue.

Comment: Thanks, i did not know any of this. Please i just want to share what took me a good while to work out and i know others will find of interest going by other posts i came across online. I was trying to install 2 versions of php, and after trying one guide (not specific to virtualmin) i was close but i kept just getting a error 500 with the new php version and little error information. In the end i worked out what the problem was and got it working, and that is what i want to share. If other users dont help each other out how will they get better, just say 'this is bad' is not enough.

Comment: please tell me what more i can do to make it better

Comment: well my question is no closed so i guess there's no chance of it coming back now /?...

Comment: @HaydenThring What do you mean "coming back?'  It's closed, true, but it's still there and so is your answer.  It doesn't look like enough people think it should be re-opened, so it'll just stay that way.

Comment: Well now its been closed i cant even ask any questions, this is a joke, its not like ive set to troll the website or mislead any one, i just wanted to help, i think ill go to unix stack where mods arent so snobby "You have reached your question limit"

Comment: If you're getting the message "You've reached your question limit," that has nothing whatsoever to do with this question.  That's a rate-limiting function built in to all SE sites and no one on this site can do anything about it.

Comment: yes it say "You have reached your question limit" but the link on the page says its a ban not a rate throttle https://serverfault.com/help/question-bans